# Function returns null even though return statement is reached

Tags: dart

I have a function inside my class that should find an object inside of a `List` using its `id` and return the matching object.

```
static Category findById(List<Category> categories, String id) {
  categories.forEach((category) {
    if (category.id == id) {
      return category;
    }
  });
}
```

However, `findById` always returns `null`. 
When debugging, `category.id` and `id` are equal and the compiler even jumps into the return statement, but the returned value is always `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from the *wrong scope*. You are actually returning to the `forEach` method instead of `findById`. Luckily, Dart has a built-in function that does what you want, i.e. [`List.firstWhere`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html):

```
static Category findById(List<Category> categories, String id) => 
    categories.firstWhere((category) => category.id == id);
```

You could also use a `for` loop instead, which is exactly what `firstWhere` does as well. This way you return in the correct scope:

```
static Category findById(List<Category> categories, String id) {
  for (Category category in categories) 
    if (category.id == id) return category;
  return null; // no matching element
}
```

You can find [more about scopes here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope).

The last `return null` is optional as [explained here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#return-values).